# How do i loop the print in python

Tags: python

```
number_1 = int(input("enter a number below 10: "))
if number_1 > 10:
    print ("its over 10 start again.")
else:
    print ("Okay lets get started")
```

how do i make it so that when a number higher than 10 is input it repeats the question. untill the person does something under 10

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop around `input`

```
number_1 = int(input("enter a number below 10: "))
while number_1 > 10:
    number_1 = int(input("its over 10 start again, enter a number below 10: "))
print("Okay lets get started")
```

Could be written another way

```
while True:
    number_1 = int(input("Enter a number below 10: "))
    if number_1 <= 10:
        print("Okay lets get started")
        break
```

Comment: thank you so much both of you have good codes for me im just a beginer

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    number_1 = int(input("enter a number below 10: "))
    while number_1 > 10:
        print ("its over 10 start again.")
        break
    if number_1 < 10:
        print ("Okay lets get started")
        break
```

This loops the input until the number is below 10 and once it is below 10 it breaks. Hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Yes thank you so so much! im just a beginer so idk whats going on

Comment: I understand what you mean. Go on to w3schools and learn about loops will surely help you